# View.removeAllViews() does not clean memory?

Tags: android, memory, viewflipper

I am using a ViewFlipper to manage some screens in my app.

Whenever a user goes to a new "level" inside my app, I call viewFlip.removeAllViews(); However I can see that this doesn't seem to clean the memory. My app goes on using more and more memory, until it crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think your problem lies directly in `ViewFlipper` children ... You may have other references that you leak. Take a look at Patrick Dubroys [memory profiling session video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) to find the source of evil

Comment: Specifically, use a DDMS heap dump and MAT to determine whether those views are being held, and if so, by what.

Comment: CommonsWare, can you send more informations about MAT? What does it mean?